# Issue with structuring breadcrumbs

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs, microdata

I have the following html to structure my breadcrumbs:

```
<ul class="browsePageBC">
   <li class="product-breadcrumb" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="/Wanita" itemprop="url" alt="" title="Wanita"><span class="product-breadcrumb-title" itemprop="title">Wanita</span></a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></li>
   <li class="product-breadcrumb" itemprop="child" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a href="/Wanita/Aksesoris" itemprop="url" alt="" title="Aksesoris"><span class="product-breadcrumb-title" itemprop="title">Aksesoris </span></a></li>
</ul>
```

When I tested this on structured data testing tools, [this is](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shopious.com%2Fitems%2F736332) what it gives me. Wondering why it's not showing/parsing the child correctly?

Comment: Note that the [`a` element can’t have an `alt` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14851121/1591669).

Answer (score 1):

Following sample code will help you to declare the parent and child property

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    <span itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
        <a rel="home" href="http://www.example.com" itemprop="url">
          <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
        </a> ›
        <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
            <a href="http://www.example.com/topic/technology/" itemprop="url">
              <span itemprop="title">Technology</span>
            </a> ›
            <span itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                <a href="http://www.example.com/tag/gadgets/" itemprop="url">
                  <span itemprop="title">Gadgets</span>
                </a> ›
                <span>Sweet Post Title Goes Here</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Let me know if these code help on your way.

Comment: Yah that's what I did.. create a first item, and embed all other children within it :=) A bit boring code .... but it makes it :=)

Answer (score 0):

Google’s documentation: [Rich Snippets – Breadcrumbs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417)

You’ll see in their examples that you either

- list all entries in the correct order (without using the `child` property), or
- use the `child` property in which case you would have to nest the child item under the parent item.

Note that each entry needs its own `itemscope`.