# SEO microdata in a div container?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, seo, search-engine, microdata

I've just started to learn about microdata in HTML. Now I have a simple question about it. I'm using **bootstrap** to design my website. So I'm using the bootstrap breadcrumb class. In every instructions how to set up the microdata correctly, it says I should add `itemtype` and `itemprop` to a div container.

So my question is:
Is it possible not to use a div container for this? Is it important to have a div-container?

My example code is something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"><a itemprop="url" href="<?= base_url(); ?>home"><span itemprop="title">Ferienwohnung</span></a></li>
            <li itemprop="child" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb" class="active"><span itemprop="title">Anfahrt</span></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microdata can be used on *any* HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20889900/1591669) (but note that some elements come with special rules). So yes, re-use your existing markup.

Side note: you are not using the [`Breadcrumb`](http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb) type correctly; the `itemprop="child"` must be specified on an HTML element that is a descendant of the parent entry’s `itemscope`. So it’s not possible to use the `child` property in a `ul` (without nesting the list entries). See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25108451/1591669) to a question where the OP used similar markup.