# Add alt attribute to ALL links in Typo3

Tags: typo3, title, typoscript, alt

I'm currently making a website accessible. Currently, there are only the title attributes defined of each link. For maximum compatibility with screen readers, I need to have the alt and the title.

Is there a way to add to each link the alt attribute with the value of the title? Best would be typoscript.

Another problem is, that the site is online and frequently visited. It has to be a method which is 100% working.

Comment: altText.data = file:current:alternative // file:current:name

Comment: @brandelizer but where do I put this?

Comment: Do you really mean links instead of images? The [`a` element can’t have an `alt` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14851121/1591669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found here : http://typo3-4-newbies.blogspot.co.at/2014/03/image-alt-text-so-hinterlegen-sie-einen.html

```
// Löscht die Standard-Konfiguration des Alt-Textes
tt_content.image.20.1.altText >
// Neuaufbau als TEXT-Objekt
tt_content.image.20.1.altText = TEXT
tt_content.image.20.1.altText {
  // zusätzliches Objekt zur Fallunterscheidung leer/befüllt
  // (zugegeben: erst nach längerem herumprobieren war das die finale Lösung)
  cObject = TEXT
  // Das Objekt erhält den Wert aus dem Feld "alternative Text",
  // den Sie direkt beim Bild eintragen können
  cObject.field = altText

  // Wenn kein Alt-Text hinterlegt wurde, wird ein TEXT-Objekt erzeugt
  ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
  ifEmpty.cObject {
    // Ich ersetze nun Teile des Original-Dateinamens
    // Da ich es übersichtlich mag, teile ich mir meine Funktion ein wenig auf
    replacement {
      10 {
        // Sucht alle Werte zwischen "/" und entfernt diese
        search = /\/(.*)\//
        useRegExp = 1
        replace =
      }
      15 {
        // Danach entferne ich die Dateiendung
        // Somit steht nur noch der reine Name der Datei da
        search = /^(.*)\.(.*)/
        useRegExp = 1
        replace = $1
      }
      20 {
        // zuletzt lösche ich die voranstehenden Punkte, 
        // sollten diese von TYPO3 gesetzt worden sein
        search = ..
        replace =
      }
    }
    // Den Wert (hier der Dateiname plus Pfad) beziehe ich aus dem Feld "image" des Inhaltselements
    field = image
    // Da im Feld "image"  die Bilder durch Komma getrennt in der Datenbank abgespeichert werden,
    // führe ich einen Optionsplit mit Komma als Trennzeichen durch. Damit kann ich jedes einzelne Bild entsprechend bearbeiten.
    // Tun Sie dies nicht, haben aber mehrere Bilder, so würde der Alt-Text des letzten Bildes bei allen anderen angezeigt werden
    split.token.char = 44
    // Gibt je das aktuelle Bild zurück
    split.returnKey.data = register : IMAGE_NUM_CURRENT
  }
}
// Vererbung der neuen Alt-Text Definitionen auf das Inhaltselement "Text mit Bild"
tt_content.textpic.20.1.altText.ifEmpty.cObject < tt_content.image.20.1.altText.ifEmpty.cObject
```