# How do I use JQuery to change one html attribute's value to equal a different attribute's value?

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

With JQuery on document load, I am trying to select each `<img>` and give it a new attribute `title` and set it to equal the value of the attribute `alt`. The `title` is what is supposed to appear in the tooltip when the user hovers over the element. Using the console, I seem to be able to select each element effectively, but something seems to go wrong when I put it all together.

The HTML:

```
<ul class="list">

<li><img href="#" src="url" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" alt="first-tooltip"></li>

<li><img href="#" src="url" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" alt="second-tooltip"></li>

<li><img href="#" src="url" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" alt="third-tooltip"></li>

</ul>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   //enable tooltips

    $('.list li').children().each( function(){  //perform function on each <a>
      var thisAltText = $(this).attr('alt');  //select the alt value
      $(this).attr('title', thisAltText);  //set title value to equal alt value
    });
});
```

As you can see, this is not working: http://codepen.io/shawnmurtagh/pen/ZpVgkz

FYI - I am using `.children()` because I need to select different list items in my actual project.

Comment: You mean `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`?

Comment: `alt` is not a valid attribute on `<a>`, by the way. You might want to just correct your HTML.

Comment: yes, thanks - still doesn't seem to work, though.

Comment: The codepen works as expected, no?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850187/is-it-correct-to-use-alt-tag-for-an-anchor-link . alt attribute is an invalid attribute on anchor tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$( ".list li" ).each(function() {
    var thisAltText = $(this).children().attr('alt');
    $(this).children().attr('title', thisAltText);
});
```

**Or**

```
$( ".list li a" ).each(function( index ) {
    var thisAltText = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(this).attr('title', thisAltText);
});
```

**Or**

```
$( ".list li" ).each(function( index ) {
    var thisAltText = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    $(this).find('img').attr('title', thisAltText);
});
```

**Or**

```
$( ".list" ).children().each(function( index ) {
    var thisAltText = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    $(this).find('img').attr('title', thisAltText);
});
```

Play here https://jsfiddle.net/47jgmzju/

Comment: Thanks - this is the best answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.list li').children().each( function(){  //perform function on each <a>
          var thisAltText = $(this).attr('alt');  //select the alt value
          $(this).attr('title', thisAltText);  //set title value to equal alt value
        });
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   //enable tooltips
    });
```

Comment: That did it. Tooltips need to be enabled after the titles have already been changed.

Comment: @smurtagh Glad , I could help. You can mark the answer as done for others' reference.