# Icon accessibility within links (aria-hidden)

Tags: icons, accessibility

Suppose I have two arrows on either end of a carousel which when clicked rotate the carousel.  I might have markup like:

```
<a class="carousel-prev" alt="Previous Item"><i class="icon-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a class="carousel-next" alt="Next Item"><i class="icon-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

In this case, does `aria-hidden="true"` attribute break accessibility, or is it okay since the outer `<a>` tag is tabbable and is using alt text?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have an aria-label on the anchor tag?  Should be a simple matter of changing your alt= to aria-label=.  No need to have a nested span with a screen reader class.

```
<a class="carousel-prev" aria-label="Previous Item"><i class="icon-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a class="carousel-next" aria-label="Next Item"><i class="icon-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

It's valid html.  Look at the "Allowed ARIA state and property attributes" section of https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element.  All aria tags are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

First, the WAI provides a full example of a working carousel: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/carousels/

Some personal observations:

1. You have to ask yourself about the interest of rotating a carousel for a blind user. One way to handle UX for blind users is to make them ignore that what they are browsing is a carousel (switching items automatically as the keyboard focus move for instance).
2. `aria-hidden` does not break the accessibility because there's nothing inside the `i` tag, tag which is not designed to be used as a portmanteau tag (like `span`).
3. As pointed out by @DiscoInfiltrator `alt` is not a valid attribute for links
4. As a small part of visually impaired users use screenreaders, you should use the `title` attribute on the `a` tag in order to make this information accessible for everyone rather than the `aria-label` which is also a good alternative.

Answer (score 1):

the `alt` attribute is not a valid attribute for links, so it not only is an accessibility concern but it is also invalid html.
See this stackoverflow post if you want to read more: 
[Is it correct to use alt tag for an anchor link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850187/is-it-correct-to-use-alt-tag-for-an-anchor-link)

I would recommend removing the alt from the link and instead include a "screenreader-only" class that will allow the text to be read but hidden from the screen. See this link from a11yproject.com on how to implement this:

http://a11yproject.com/posts/how-to-hide-content/

I would recommend altering the code to look like this:

```css
.sr-only {
  position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
    padding:0 !important;
    border:0 !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="carousel-prev"><span class="sr-only">Previous Item</span><i class="icon-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a class="carousel-next"><span class="sr-only">Next Item</span><i class="icon-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```