# What valid alt attribute should be for each image in a slideshow?

Tags: html, accessibility, slideshow, semantic-markup, alt-attribute

In a website directory, every business has a slideshow with several images. If I don't know what kind of picture is in each case, what should be the best way to handle the `alt` attribute for each image/link?

Example (edited)

```
<ul class="slideshow">
   <li>
     <a href="img1_full.jpg" ><img src="img1_thumb" alt=""></a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="img2_full.jpg" ><img src="img1_thumb" alt=""></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you don't know what the image is, you have know way of knowing how to describe it.

Comment: `alt` value is simply text that describes the image in literal terms. ex. an image of the *Mona Lisa* would be: *A painting of a dark haired woman with arms crossed and a slight smile*

Comment: @zer00ne - Sometimes it is, but not always. An `alt` value provides replacement text for the image in its context. See the [alt usage decision tree](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/decision-tree/) for well founded information on what an alt text should contain.

Answer (score 2):

`alt="Slideshow image 1 of Business X"`, etc.

Since you do not know what the images are, this would be a valid option. It tells someone who is using a screen reader, or for whatever reason cannot see the image (it doesn't load), that the image is part of a slideshow. It also tells which image it is and what business it relates to.

For extra credit, you could use an API such as the Cloud Vision API that can analyze the content of an image and return a short phrase that describes it.

Comment: Read [F30: Failure of Success Criterion 1.1.1 and 1.2.1 due to using text alternatives that are not alternatives](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F30.html). Terms like "slideshow", "image 1 of" are useless when using a screenreader, and having no alternative at all is better than having a non descriptive information.

Answer (score 0):

[The `a` element can’t have an `alt` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851121/1591669).

Assuming that you use `img`:

- If the images in the slideshow are only decoration, you have to use empty `alt` values.
- If the link goes to a page (instead of the image), the `alt` value [has to describe the purpose of the link](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/48817/17023), not the image. So for example, if a slide shows a product image and is linked to the product page, the `alt` value could be the product name.
- If the link goes to the image (e.g., in a higher resolution) or if the slide is not linked, the `alt` value has to describe the image.

[Exception](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#guidance-for-conformance-checkers): If you automatically generate the markup and have no way of adding a suitable `alt` value, you can use the attribute `generator-unable-to-provide-required-alt` (with an empty value) instead of `alt`. It’s non-conforming, but validators may ignore the error, and it’s in any case better than providing an unsuitable `alt` value.