# how to add alter link in <a> tag in html

Tags: html, tags, twig

I'm implementing  tag in my website. I load data from two different sources.

Because if one source(DB) is not available(not in connection), the data comes from second source(DB).

In this scenario, my  tag have a two different link to reach for every page.

My doubt is if any possibility to add alter source in  tag like **img alt** function

**CODE**

```
<a href="{{url1}}">url</a> // If source 1

<a href="{{url2}}">url</a> // If source 2
```

If possible to represent the above two link as below link,

```
<a href="{{url1}}" alt="{{url2}}">url</a>
```

Comment: I think in a tag alt is not there.For fulfill your requirement you have to write code for it

Comment: OK. Thanks for your replay.

Comment: You can use [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) and write the code to get the data from attribute when the source is not available.

Comment: are you using angular?

Comment: also, what do you mean when you say if one source is not available? Like if `url1` is undefined?

Comment: @codeherk I am not using angular. And i mention not available means undefined

Comment: You did not mention that not available means undefined.

Comment: WIth HTML alone, you cannot achieve this... you would need to include JavaScript to manipulate/validate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No -  generally, the `alt` attribute is for the purpose of showing alternative text. However, according to the specification the `alt` is not allowed in the anchor tags. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14851121/4185234).
2. You should use Javascript to replace the source if your run time environment matches conditions.

   ```
     if (!url1) 
       document.getElementById('#my-anchor').href = url2;
   ```
3. If using twig template, use conditional operator to resolve this problem,

   For example,

```
  <a href="{{(url1 != '')? url1 : url2 }}"></a>
```

Comment: This could be simplified to `<a href="{{ url1|default(url2) }}"></a>`