# How to remove label on hover of react icon file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, document

I am working in a project with reactjs and when i hover on an icon file (after uploading it o pre-charging it) this displays:
[image]

Do you know how i can remove this?

Comment: Post your code and also tell us if you are using some design/component framework

Answer (score 1):

The 'hint' you see when you hover is a default browser behavior, but you can suggest different text using the 'title' attribute:

```
<a href="/mydownload.png" target="_new" title="Click to download 'image.png'">image.png</a>
```

And then "Click to download 'image.png'" would replace the string in your black box there.

As per [this question about link alt text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850187/is-it-correct-to-use-alt-tag-for-an-anchor-link/14851121)

Comment: for the styling of the tooltip in the OP screenshot, i would guess that this is not the default tooltip of the browser.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, that's quite possible. I'll keep an eye on the question to see if we get some code to work with.