# I have a simple question regarding alt and title

Tags: html

I have a really simple question.

In HTML links (a href), can I use title and alt? Or only Title?

I know for images title and alt can be used at the same time. But what about links as I have mentioned?

Thank you.

Trying to get an answer to a simple question.

Example:

```
<a href="#" title="demo" alt="demo">test</a>
```

I have searched online but couldn't find a definitive answer.

Comment: alt is an alternative text you see in case the image wont render, title is something you see when you hover over the image, so they are 2 seperate things, yes, you can use either 1 or both, but better on both than 1. SEO technically its even recommended both

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I'm going to include both title and alt in my images and URLs.

Comment: Using `alt` on `<a>` not only makes zero sense, but also leaves you with **invalid HTML**. @Dorvalla Please provide reference where, as you claim, for SEO it is recommended to use `alt` attributes on textual elements like `<a>`.

Comment: @connexo i refer more to an image here than an anchor. Title in an anchor is acceptable, even prefered, and you are right, after a quick check,  that alt makes no sense, however, it is not invalid. HTML won't block it and it is allowed, but has no impact on the element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850187/is-it-correct-to-use-alt-tag-for-an-anchor-link

Comment: The only place to verify if something is valid HTML is https://validator.w3.org. Try it out, and you will get **Error: Attribute `alt` not allowed on element `a` at this point.**

Answer (score -1):

some browser will not support your image or link or title that is why we always use alt. alt is alternative text which shuld be shown when an image or link is not supported by browser

Comment: So, I don't fully understand. Should we use alt for only images and titles for <a> links?

Comment: No, images can have both, a title is only used for anchors.

Comment: no no, you can use alt for both images and links.

Comment: use alt tag to describe the item in detail and the title to provide extra details in links(anchor tags)

Comment: 1. There is no *alt tag*. It's an `alt` **attribute**. 2. No, using `alt` on anchors is not valid.

Answer (score -1):

some browser will not support your image.link is not supported by browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).